# Nested function skews return type of its parent

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, case

I'm writing a function and having a strange issue. I'm using pattern matching, and then an internal function which uses a slightly changed but almost identical pattern and it isn't compiling:

```
def isTriangular(n: Int): Boolean = {
  n match {
   case n if n < 1 => false
   case _ => triangularMaths(n, 1)
  }

  def triangularMaths(j:Int, counter: Int): Boolean = (j, counter) match {
    case _ if j-counter == 0 => true
    case _ if j-counter < 0 => false
    case _ => triangularMaths(j-counter, counter+1)
  }
}
```

The fix for this is I simply make them two seperate methods, and they work as long as `triangularMaths` isn't nested. However, since `triangularMaths` is specific to `triangular` only, I'd like it to be nested. However, when I do this, my compiler complains, telling me I am returning `Unit`, rather than the expected `Boolean` . This doesn't quite make sense, as once the original case brackets is resolved, returning true or false, it should go to the end of the method, and complete, correct? What's the fix?

Comment: Hint: the return value of a method is the value of the last expression evaluated in the method. Hint #2: what is the last expression evaluated in the method? Hint #3: what is the value of a function definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your method is the last declaration in scope, which makes the compiler emit the `Unit` value as the return type. Decompiled code looks like this:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  def isTriangular(n: Int): Boolean = {
    n match {
      case (n @ _) if n.<(1) => false
      case _ => triangularMaths(n, 1)
    };
    def triangularMaths(j: Int, counter: Int): Boolean = scala.Tuple2.apply[Int, Int](j, counter) match {
      case _ if j.-(counter).==(0) => true
      case _ if j.-(counter).<(0) => false
      case _ => triangularMaths(j.-(counter), counter.+(1))
    };
    ()
  };
```

First define `triangularMaths`, and then invoke it:

```
def isTriangular(n: Int): Boolean = {
  def triangularMaths(j: Int, counter: Int): Boolean = (j, counter) match {
    case _ if j - counter == 0 => true
    case _ if j - counter < 0 => false
    case _ => triangularMaths(j - counter, counter + 1)
  }

  n match {
    case n if n < 1 => false
    case _ => triangularMaths(n, 1)
  }
}
```

Another possibility would be to assign the pattern match to a value, and then return that value as the last expression of the method. But, that would make the compiler complain about forward reference, which you could fix by making it a `lazy val` instead. I would stick the the re-ordering approach.

Comment: Aha, thanks. I had tried setting a var `b: boolean = false` as the first line of `isTriangular` and then set the second line of `n match` to be: `case _ => b == triangularMaths(n, 1) ` and then return `b` right before the closing bracket of the whole thing, but it wouldn't remember the change to `b` if it got evaluated to true.